# extjs4 xtype:container add scroll listener

Tags: scroll, extjs4, listener, containers

How can I add a scroll listener on an extjs 4 container?

I tried:

```
{   xtype: 'container',
    region: 'center',
    id: 'centerPanel',
    autoScroll: true,
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (c) {
             c.getEl().on('scroll', function () {
                 console.log('scrolling');
             });
             c.getEl().on('click', function () {
                 console.log('click');
             });
        }
    },
}
```

But it seems this does not work anymore, worked on ext 3. Anyone has any ideas? The click event works, the scroll does not.

Comment: which exact version are you running?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. 'viewready' instead of 'afterender' and use grid.view

```
viewready: function(grid,eOpts){
    grid.view.getEl().on('scroll', function(e, t) { 
         console.log("scroll");
    });
}
```